# What is the better way to use a my_sql database with a C# .Net software?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, database, visual-studio-2008

I would like to create a C# .Net software linked to a database.

I had a look at some solutions found on google but none of them convinced me ...

So, what do you think is the better way to integrate a my_sql database into a C# .Net Software. Of course a nice integration into visual studio would be better :p

Thanks.

PS : I use Ruby on Rails at work and i love the Database Model, very simple and quite powerful ! Is there an equivalent for C# ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the ADO.Net connector from here: http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Works great for what we need.

Comment: thanks i'm using this solution :)
I found a basic exemple :
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CsharpAndMysql.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have an answer for MySql but have you looked at [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/)? I've used this RDBMS for a couple of pet projects and have been very happy with the results. They have a great embedded version that can be xcopy deployed along with your .Net application. And best of all, it is free to use and distribute (it's open source).

They also have a [.Net data provider](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=files&id=netprovider) available.

Answer (score 0):

To speak to your PS, you can check out [The ASP.NET MVC Framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/). It brings the model-view-controller pattern you're familiar with from Rails to ASP.NET. Here's a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) to the Wikipedia entry.